# Can't pass attribute through Simulation Output node

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I'm trying to attach the vertices of mesh A to mesh B using the Sample Nearest node. Since mesh B moves (in my case using a Simple Deform modifier) the sampling of the nearest vertices should only happen in the first five frames, to make mesh A stick to mesh B, while it deforms.
The general setup works as it should but I need to use simulation nodes to make the sampling stop after the first five frames while keeping the index numbers of the nearest vertices.

[image]

Unfortunately according to the Viewer the "ParentIndex" socket of the SimulatinOutput node outputs just zeros. It seems I'm missing something essential here.

Comment: just a hint: if you provide a blend file you would attract way more people who want to help who are too lazy to rebuild your tree (like me)

Comment: Maybe your setup doesn't work for a different reason than you think? It seems your *Sample Position* is always $<0, 0, 0>$…